# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php

I have this PHP code where I create a dropdownlist from the database. But when I run the application it fires an error `Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in ----\register.php on line 79`.

```
<select name="country">
<?php
    $country_result = $dataclass->get_Countries();
    while ($country_row = $country_result->fetch()){ //line 79
        echo "<option value='" . $country_row["country_id"] . "'>" . $country_row["country_name"] . "</option>" . "\n";
    }
?>
</select>
```

I have used such methods anywhere and they worked, but when using it for drop down list it doesn't work.

get_Country() method contents:

```
function get_Countries() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_countries;";
    return $this->dbconn->fetch($sql);
}
```

$this->dbconn->fetch() contents:

```
function fetch($sql, $data=array()) {
    try{
        $STH = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $STH->execute($data);
        return $STH;
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Could it be because 'data' parameter is an array?

Comment: Can you confirm that $country_result is valid result? I think previous call to query database was not correct, so subsequent call to result will fall into this error as well.

Comment: `get_Countries()` obviously doesn't return an object. Its not possible to go any further without nothing the class (and its implementation) of `$dataclass`.

Comment: if get_Countries() doesn't return a new object, there's your error. Make sure it's not an array or a database resource, for example. Try var_dump() to check the type and properties of $country_result.

Comment: Please update the question instead of posting code in the comments!

Comment: @Mark Hünermund Jensen I tried it but it is saying `Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given`

Comment: What does $thus->dbconn->fetch do?

Comment: I'll admit I'm not familiar with PDO. But yes, it could be because it's an array - the result of get_Countries MUST be an object with the method "fetch" as it is used now. Try var_dump the result, and see what you get.

Comment: The solution for my problem was that the dataclass instantiation was being carried out within a method and therefore was a non-object.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function get_Countries() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_countries;";
    return $this->dbconn->query($sql);
}
```